# drawing multiple circles with turtle in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am having problems drawing circles and fitting the equation together I want to draw 3 circles in random locations that I have set with random radiuses like I set up but I can't fit the circumference equation in the draw class for it to work. like this[image]

```
    import turtle
from turtle import RawTurtle


class circle:
    def __init__(self, R, D, turtle):
        self._a = R
        self._b = D
        self._turtle = turtle
        turtle.up()

    def set_initial_position(self, x: float, y: float):
        self._turtle.setpos(x, y)

    def draw(self):
        t = self._turtle
        for _ in range(int(draw)):
            turtle.circle(25)
            turtle.forward(10)
        t.up()

    def hide(self):
        self._turtle.clear()


r1 = circle(5, 5, RawTurtle(turtle.getscreen()))
r2 = circle(5, 10, RawTurtle(turtle.getscreen()))
r3 = circle(10, 20, RawTurtle(turtle.getscreen()))
r2.set_initial_position(-50, 100)
r3.set_initial_position(60, 200)
r1.draw()
r2.draw()
r3.draw()
r2.hide()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: "I can't fit the circumference equation in the draw class for it to work" -- this is unclear to me. Why do you need this equaton and what do you mean by "can't fit"? You can always add more code to a method--it's not like the editor has any limits on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell what your program is trying to do from your explanation and code but below I've reworked it into something that runs from which you should be able to build what you really want:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class circle:
    def __init__(self, radius, degrees, turtle):
        self._r = radius
        self._d = degrees
        self._turtle = turtle

        self._turtle.penup()

    def set_initial_position(self, x, y):
        self._turtle.setposition(x, y)

    def draw(self):
        self._turtle.pendown()

        self._turtle.circle(self._r, extent=self._d)

        self._turtle.penup()

    def hide(self):
        self._turtle.clear()

screen = Screen()

r1 = circle(150, 45, Turtle())
r2 = circle(15, 180, Turtle())
r3 = circle(100, 360, Turtle())

r2.set_initial_position(-50, 100)
r3.set_initial_position(60, 200)

r1.draw()
r2.draw()
r1.hide()
r3.draw()

screen.mainloop()
```

You seem to be using the tkinter embedded turtle API for a standalone turtle program so I've switched the method calls.  And as the Python error notes, you use a `draw` variable which you fail to define.  (And you shouldn't define one as you already have a `draw` function -- choose a different name for the variable.)

Comment: oh i got it that was the mistake also the answer is correct but I just had to change the degrees to 360 to each of the drawings but thanks I got my mistake, any ideas on how you would improve the code ? don't write it maybe a lecture or a short idea would help